# How to access information in ansible yum list result?

Tags: ansible

could you help me accessing some information in the result of the yum list module?

This is my task:

```
- name: check if lgto networker is installed
  yum:
    list: "{{ (item | basename | splitext)[0] }}"
    state: present
  register: yum_result
  with_fileglob:
    - "lgt*.rpm"
```

When i debug my registered var `yum_result` i got this output:

```
ok: [XX.XX.XX.XXX] => {
    "yum_result": [
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null, 
            "_ansible_item_result": true, 
            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
            "_ansible_parsed": true, 
            "changed": false, 
            "failed": false, 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "allow_downgrade": false, 
                    "conf_file": null, 
                    "disable_gpg_check": false, 
                    "disablerepo": null, 
                    "enablerepo": null, 
                    "exclude": null, 
                    "install_repoquery": true, 
                    "installroot": "/", 
                    "list": "lgtoclnt-8.2.4.9-1.x86_64", 
                    "name": null, 
                    "security": false, 
                    "skip_broken": false, 
                    "state": "installed", 
                    "update_cache": false, 
                    "validate_certs": true
                }
            }, 
            "item": "/data/playbooks/roles/backup_networker/files/lgtoclnt-8.2.4.9-1.x86_64.rpm", 
            "results": [
                {
                    "arch": "x86_64", 
                    "envra": "0:lgtoclnt-8.2.4.9-1.x86_64", 
                    "epoch": "0", 
                    "name": "lgtoclnt", 
                    "release": "1", 
                    "repo": "installed", 
                    "version": "8.2.4.9", 
                    "yumstate": "installed"
                }
            ]
        }
```

How can i access the information in the last results block?

```
                    "arch": "x86_64", 
                    "envra": "0:lgtoclnt-8.2.4.9-1.x86_64", 
                    "epoch": "0", 
                    "name": "lgtoclnt", 
                    "release": "1", 
                    "repo": "installed", 
                    "version": "8.2.4.9", 
                    "yumstate": "installed"
```

I've tried something like `yum_result.results.yumstate` or `yum_result[2].yumstate`, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the result with

```yaml
yum_result.results[0].yumstate
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`yum_result` to access registered dictionary
`yum_result.results` to access the list of registered iterations
`yum_result.results[-1]` to access result of last iteration
`yum_result.results[-1].yumstate` to access it's `yumstate` status

Comment: Thanks! But im still not getting why to use [-1], i thought yum_results is an array or json construct? Regarding this topic i can't find any doc on ansible.com...

Comment: When im using -debug var: yum_result.results[-1].yumstate i get an error: ok: [xx.xx.xx.xxx] => {"yum_result.results[-1].yumstate": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"}